# AWK joining two files on a specific column

Tags: awk, joincolumn

I'm trying to join two files on one of their columns and the output should be the columns of the second file and some of the columns from the first file.

For example my first file is:

> subscriberid unsubscribetime unsubscribeip listid statid unsubscribed

and my second file is:

> listid statid listname ownername owneremail createdate subscriberid bouncetype bouncetime bouncerule

I need to join them on the "statid" column which is 5th in the first file and 2nd in the second file. After that add 2nd, 3rd and 6th column from the first file. The output should be:

> listid statid listname ownername owneremail createdate subscriberid bouncetype bouncetime bouncerule **unsubscribetime unsubscribeip unsubscribed**

I am having trouble understanding the syntax, but I was using this command:

```
awk 'NR==FNR{a[$5]=$2;next} $2 in a{print $0, a[$5]}' file1 file2
```

I thought it would give me the file2 columns, because of "print $0" and the second column form file one which is set to a[$5]=$2, but it only outputs the file2 columns.

Where am I making a mistake, please? 
How to join the 2nd, 3rd and 6th column from file1 to file2?

Any help/explanations are very much appreciated!

*both files in this example have only one row*

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I'm sure if you see this and think about it a bit you'll figure it out:

```
$ awk 'NR==FNR{a[$5]=$2" "$3" "$6;next} $2 in a{print $0, a[$2]}' file1 file2
listid statid listname ownername owneremail createdate subscriberid bouncetype bouncetime bouncerule unsubscribetime unsubscribeip unsubscribed
```