# How to join two files based on one column in AWK

Tags: awk

I have two files both with millions of records in (not the same amount of records in each)

File A

```
46901208,(SPUR OFF) FFERM LLIDIART WERDD,WRECSAM
85315934,A4077 FROM CRUGHYWEL ROAD,CRUGHYWEL
46402576,A4085 COFNOD WEDI CAU,BEDDGELERT
46400001,A4085 CYLCHFAN CAEATHRO,CAEATHRO
```

File B

```
46408008,1
46400005,1
46400001,4
46402576,3
```

I want to merge the two files based on matching $1, the ones that don't match I don't want them being output.

Desired output:

```
46402576,A4085 COFNOD WEDI CAU,BEDDGELERT,3
46400001,A4085 CYLCHFAN CAEATHRO,CAEATHRO,4
```

How can I do this? 
Thanks

Comment: Answered hundreds of times, searching your title on google brings up tons of results on this site and U&L.

Comment: I know I have looked, and tried them but can't get my head around the answers and make it work for mine @９９９９９９９９９９９９９９９９９９９９９９９９９９９９９９

Comment: possible duplicate of [AWK joining two files on a specific column](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/17342954/awk-joining-two-files-on-a-specific-column)

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Try this

```
awk -F"," 'BEGIN{OFS=","} {if (NR==FNR) {a[$1]=$2; next} if ($1 in a) {print $1, $2, $3, a[$1]}}' f2 f1
```

---

**UPDATE**

Use `awk -F"," -f your_awk.awk f2 f1` format. In `your_awk.awk` file:

```
BEGIN{OFS=","} {if (NR==FNR) {a[$1]=$2; next} if ($1 in a) {print $1, $2, $3, a[$1]}}
```

Comment: I am running on windows command prompt and getting the error: awk: cmd. line:1: 'BEGIN{OFS=,}
awk: cmd. line:1: ^ Invalid char ''' in expression

Answer (score 5):

I know that you have asked about `awk` but there is special command to do that and it's called `join`:

1) If your files have already sorted:

```
$ join -j 1 -t, A B
46400001,A4085 CYLCHFAN CAEATHRO,CAEATHRO,4
46402576,A4085 COFNOD WEDI CAU,BEDDGELERT,3
```

Here we are joining files `A` and `B` by 1st field and use comma as separator of the fields.

2) If your files unsorted and you want to do all the things in one shot with `bash`:

```
$ join -j 1 -t, <(sort A) <(sort B)
46400001,A4085 CYLCHFAN CAEATHRO,CAEATHRO,4
46402576,A4085 COFNOD WEDI CAU,BEDDGELERT,3
```

Comment: Hi, I m facing an error with this join command. Although it joins successfully, the joined columns are not on the same line, it is on the next line. ie  
`46400001,A4085 CYLCHFAN CAEATHRO,CAEATHRO\n  
                ,4`